# CURL Post method in c++

Tags: c++, libcurl

Suppose we have a HTTP request like following:

```
POST /safebrowsing/downloads?client=Firefox&appver=3.0.8&pver=2.2&wrkey=AKEgNiux-3bBzAgJeFWgqbneh_GLc2OrmgXnpxPrdH1-hFpbAM8k1ovPA8GB_UMRueBHnL3QJ7gsdQOWVm6QJr_VZNgAm8jmLQ== HTTP/1.1
Host: safebrowsing.clients.google.com
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; U; Linux i686; en-US; rv:1.9.0.8) Gecko/2009033100 Ubuntu/9.04 (jaunty) Firefox/3.0.8
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Language: en-us,en;q=0.5
Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate
Accept-Charset: ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.7
Keep-Alive: 300
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 120
Content-Type: text/plain
Cookie: PREF=ID=551a1b8848e36099:U=e6fa7464d7c48884:FF=0:TM=1327553284:LM=1345022478:S=Qd0IssyrqLi17a4s; NID=62=R9Y5bkQ5iLF8zlyhma1gnRBfxPDoWuG2FibC2wc5u0eAIQgAuo4WCXMeLhdPZ7FXJEpN2Sw1a6da6QUNP7OC5OqTYK0Y39vd6c2fUh4BhY2B5CGsKtHuQ5RCpSnefSkb

goog-malware-shavar;a:83372-91327:s:59904-95254:mac
goog-phish-shavar;a:227421-233955,235041-235401:s:107142-110470:mac
```

I already built up the part of code to handle the headers. However, the message-body part I'm not sure how to deal with. I have read CURL sample code, they provide solution for HTTP form POST which is not the way to handle my data. Does anyone know what parameter I should use to handle message-body using `curl_easy_setopt()` function?

Answer (score 6):

FYI: cURL provides a very convenient option that lists the ad-hoc options for a given HTTP request:

```
--libcurl <file> Dump libcurl equivalent code of this command line
```

When in doubt you should perform your request via cURL (and corresponding options, e.g. to perform a POST, etc) while using this option since it outputs the list of `curl_easy_setopt` options:

```
curl --libcurl out.c http://stackoverflow.com/ > /dev/null
```

Then open the `out.c` file within your editor:

```
...
curl_easy_setopt(hnd, CURLOPT_URL, "http://stackoverflow.com/");
curl_easy_setopt(hnd, CURLOPT_PROXY, NULL);
curl_easy_setopt(hnd, CURLOPT_NOPROGRESS, 0);
...
```

Comment: That's really handy, I can't quite believe I didn't know that existed.

Answer (score 0):

```
const char *post_data = "any_data";
...
curl_easy_setopt(curl_handle, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_easy_setopt(curl_handle, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, post_data);
```

Comment: Thanks to your reply, I have tried put the message-body into char* and using CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS to set. However, the result I got from wireshark showed it didn't rebuild the http request correctly. I'm wondering whether is it because CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS can handle form data only?

Comment: CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS can be any array of characters. May be you show part of your code where you creating and executing curl request?