# can't figure out the libcurl C/C++ code equivalent of a curl command

Tags: c++, libcurl

I'm currently working on a visual studio C++ project that needs to use libcurl to access some apis of my website which uses Django.

I'm using django-tastypie to provide api, and right now I can use this api by using this curl command:

```
curl --dump-header - -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X PATCH --data '{"body": "This actually is my last post."}' http://localhost:8000/api/v1/entry/4/
```

to update data on my server. As a test, it works, but what I really need is to write code in C/C++ with libcurl that does the same.

I'm just starting to look at libcurl and not quite sure how to do that. I assume that I should use `curl_easy_setopt` but I can't find the right options to set.

So my question is

1. Is it possible to use libcurl to achieve the same goal as that command? I'm not familiar with libcurl.
2. If so, how to set options like `-x PATCH` and `content-Type`? I looked at the [document](http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/curl_easy_setopt.html) and didn't seem to find how.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: SO is a **Question and Answer** site not a _write my code for me_ site. Please read [this FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq) and [this FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask) for information on how use SO and post appropriate questions. Then when you encounter a specific problem post a question and try to include a [Short Self Contained Correct/Compilable Example - SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) of the code you're having trouble with.

Comment: @CaptainObvlious Thanks for reminding. Maybe the way I put my question is problematic but I want help to write this code not just code.

Comment: Use `--libcurl` command-line option to figure it out: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12418787/curl-post-method-in-c/12581432#12581432

Answer (score 0):

As @deltheil suggested, I tried `--libcurl`.

But notice the code generated isn't quite right in my case. The `-H "Content-Type: application/json"` part wasn't in the code.

You need to set headers like this

```
headers = curl_slist_append(headers, "Content-Type: application/json");
curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, headers);
```

But the option `--libcurl` is quite helpful.

This [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11973994/json-requests-in-c-using-libcurl) about json requests in C helped me a lot.